# SQL Server : copy table data with FK Constraint

Tags: sql-server

I import data into a SQL Server database from Excel.

The data is inserted into a `tmptable` which has no primary key defined.

`tmptable`:

```
course, trainer, jockey, horse, won, pos, date
```

I want to copy the data from `tmptable` into another table `mastertable` which  has a primary key column.

`mastertable`:

```
coursefk, trainerfk, jockeyfk, horsefk, won, pos, date.
```

The columns suffixed `'fk'` refer to individual other tables.

My hope is that during the `insert into mastertable`, the script would take the value of `course` column from `tmptable` and refer to the table `Courses` for the appropriate value to be placed into `mastertable`. The primary and foreign key relationships between the tables have been created, but I cannot create a script that will achieve what I want.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `join` `tmptable` with other foreign key tables.

Something like this.

```
INSERT INTO mastertable(coursefk, trainerfk, jockeyfk, horsefk, won, pos, date)
SELECT mastercourse.coursefk, mastertrainer.trainerfk, masterjockey.jockeyfk, masterhorse.horsefk, won, pos, date
FROM tmptable
LEFT JOIN mastercourse ON mastercourse.course = tmptable.course 
LEFT JOIN mastertrainer ON mastertrainer.trainer = tmptable.trainer
LEFT JOIN masterjockey ON masterjockey.jockey = tmptable.jockey
LEFT JOIN masterhorse ON masterhorse.horse = tmptable.horse
```

***Note:** Since I do not know structure of other FK tables, Please replace and use appropriate table and column names.*